# What is the normal fuel consumption for a 1995 Toyota Carina E 1.6 CC 4A engine?

Tags: toyota, fuel-consumption, carina

What is the normal fuel consumption for injection type Toyota carina e 1.6 cc 
4A engine?
My 1995 Toyota Carina e car gives 9.5km/l in city and 12
km/l on highways.
How can I increase it more? toyota carina e 1995 model 1.6cc

Comment: As the Carina is apparently a model sold in Europe, I was hoping to find a European version of the US's http://fueleconomy.gov but I could not.  Anyone know if such a site exists?  Also, for US readers, the OP is reporting about 22 mpg city and 28 mpg highway - seems a little bit low for a mid-size car but maybe not excessively so.

Comment: For what it's worth, the closest US model, according to Wikipedia, seems to be the Toyota Celica.  http://fueleconomy.gov reports that a 1995 Celica with a 1.8 L engine (smallest available in the US model), when new, was rated at 23 mpg (9.7 km/l) city, 31 mpg (13.1 km/l) highway.

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid idling
2. Drive in Top gear when possible
3. Keep the Tires inflated to factory specifications
4. Avoid hard accelerations and decelerations

Answer (score 0):

That sounds about right for that model. The only things you could do is make the car as light and easy running as possible, e.g.

- remove the spare tyre and carry a patch kit and air compressor instead.
- fill your fuel tank only 50%. This should save a good 20kg to 25kg.
- go on a diet ;)
- Get alloy wheels if you don't have already
- inflate your tyres properly
- take it to a tuner to remap the engine management unit. They usually
  lean out the air/fuel ratio to give you a bit more performance, but
  at the same time a leaner air/fuel ratio means you're using less fuel
  per cylinder stroke. This will make the car run slightly hotter, but
  seeing as it's not a turbo vehicle, it's not a problem.

Comment: Leaner ratio would not give better performance, unless it was too rich before. A lambda slightly below 1 usually gives best performance, but that means a richer mixture.

Comment: A leaner ratio does in fact give greater performance. The problem with that is that leaner means more prone to knocking. A perfect petrol would be able to run at 14.7:1 under WOT, but because the extra heat produces knock, you have to inject extra to cool down the combustion and bring down EGT's. Manufacturers leave a wide margin for error, which you can fine tune based on how lucky you feel.

Comment: If you are talking about the fuel consumption when you say performance, then I understand. You won't get better engine power on a lean mixture. Also when adjusting to a lean mixture, be cautious of your NOX emissions, they rise of you go too lean.

Comment: I mean both. Fuel economy is the obvious one, but under WOT, cars are tuned to run slightly richer than they have to for reasons of safety and homologation. E.g. my Subaru has the Australian 98RON map on it, but it's so conservative that it runs perfectly fine on our 95RON South African fuel. There is a large margin for fine tuning which will gain a lot of performance for 98, but render you incapable of filling up with 95.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air%E2%80%93fuel_ratio#/media/File:Ideal-stoichiometry.jpg
Maximum power and best economy is on different sides of the graph. The mapping can give you more performance and better fuel economy, but saying that it is because they lean out the air/fuel ratio is wrong.

Comment: The page you linked to explains exactly what I'm saying: engines don't run at the optimal air/fuel ratio at all times. They are detuned to provide a margin for error. Taking the car for a software tune will bring the maps closer to optimal based on the fuel in the car. This involves leaning out the mix slightly and setting a more aggressive timing advance, both of which produce greater power AND better economy because you're working closer to the optimal threshold without exceeding it.

Comment: All right, I see what you mean, thanks for educating me =)